# FFT butterfly diagram

Tags: computer-science, signal-processing, computational-mathematics, fast-fourier-transform

I got confused in the FFT butterfly diagram. Can someone please help me understand it?

If I have the vector $x = (-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)$, and I want to apply FFT to it using the Butterfly diagram, how is the procedure exactly done? I've found these diagrams on the internet, but I don't know how to read them.

It is in my understanding that at first step we take $x(0) = -3$ and $x(2) = -1$, but then what do we do with them? Add them and multiply by something? Please explain.

I have a sample 4-point diagram where $x(0)=0$ and $x(2)=2$ get transformed to $1$, and $x(1) = 1$ and $x(3) = 1$ get transformed into $0$. But I don't know how exactly that happens. Would appreciate a good clarification. It seems very vague to me so far.

Comment: at first forget the butterfly and see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613562/fast-fourier-transform-as-matrix-factorization/1613659#1613659 , then the butterfly should be obvious to you

Comment: So, when we take $x(0)$ and $x(2)$, i.e. two even coefficients from the initial vector, do we need to add them together and then multiply by $W_N^0$, and, likewise, for $x(1)$ and $x(3)$, add them together and multiply by $W_N^?$ Can you please clarify what power should it be there for $W_N$ for the odd case?

Comment: did you understand all the steps I wrote in the link ? if you start with $x = [x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3)]$, then set $y_0 = [x(0),x(2)], y_1 = [x(1),x(3)]$, compute the DFT of $y_0$ and $y_1$ separately, and mix them to obain the DFT of $x$